# FASTAPI - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, mysql, blob, fastapi

I am trying to save a BLOB to a MySQL Database, the snippet below tries to convert the file to binary before saving.

```
            contents = CV.file.read()
            with open(CV.filename, 'wb+') as f:
                f.write(contents)
        except Exception:
            return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
        finally:
            CV.file.close()
```

However, I keep getting the error below stating that there is a `UnicodeDecodeError`. However the file still get saved in the database even with this error.

```
fast-rest-app-1     | UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Please note: I'm trying to save files like png, docx or pdf.

Comment: The characters in your blob are not encoded UTF-8

Comment: Where does it say that `CV.file` should be read in "binary"?

Comment: The part that specify 'wb' does that @RickJames

Comment: How can I make if UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I don't understand the language -- you seem to "read()" the file before "open()".